# Schedule a System Reboot with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I need to schedule an AppleScript for reboot the system every day at 08:30.
This computer does have yet an automatic boot scheduled with system preferences so I cannot use it again.

the script I can use is this:

> `tell application "System Events"
>   restart 
>   end tell`

what is the best method to call this script at a certain time every day?

Thank you

Comment: I'm triyng the method of run the script app from iCal alert and it's rebooting. The problem is that it does not stop! It continues to reboot in an infinite loop... What's wrong? I have to rename the file app from terminal of recovery mode for stop this loop.

Comment: You do release that this command will cause the system to reboot without any warning and no way to stop it? Not really a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all! 
I tried all the methods you wrote and I found that for my case, the best way is using crontab.

So I did in Terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

and added this line:

```
30 08 * * * osascript /path/to/my/script.app
```

So every day at 08:30 the system reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the folder `~/library/LaunchAgents`, you can create a plist file that looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>user.system_events.restart</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>tell application &quot;System Events&quot; to restart</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Write it in a plain-text text editor, save it as (typically) `user.system_events.restart.plist` (whatever string you used for the label value, with a 'plist' extension). Then either restart your machine or run the following command in terminal:

```
launchctl load '~/Library/LaunchAgents/user.system_events.restart.plist'
```

That should get launchd to run the System Events `restart` command at 8:30 am.

If you don't have access to that folder because of some administrator restriction you could work around this with an  AppleScript app. let me know if that's the case.

Comment: **1.** The OP stated 08:30, so why not use that instead of an arbitrary time? **2.** 23:30 **is not** "universal time", its's 24-hour time format. **3.** Please do not suggest one reboot in cases such as this **when it is not at all necessary**!

Comment: @user3439894 — I fixed the time thing (missed that, somehow). But don't be silly about the reboot. This user clearly reboots his computer every day anyway, and that is (conceptually) a far easier way to load a launchd job than playing with terminal.

Comment: There is nothing silly about my third point. A good answer is written not only to answer the question asked of the OP but for others that will read it as well. Suggesting one reboot to make a change when it is not at all necessary to do so, is extremely bad form and is exactly why I would not upvote your answer! The proper thing to do is `launchctl load` not reboot! That said, if you had suggested to reboot as an alternative to `launchctl load` instead of suggesting reboot first, I wouldn't have made it a point.